# Having no performance problems with threading and Python's Global Interpreter Lock. Scalability?

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

I have been having no problems with performance with Python's Global Interpreter Lock. I've had to make a few things thread-safe - despite common advice, the GIL does NOT automatically guarantee thread-safety - but I've got a program commonly running upwards of 10 threads, where all of them can be active at any time, including together. It is a somewhat complex asynchronous messaging system.

I understand multiprocessing and am even using Celery in this program, but the solution would have to be very convoluted to work through multiprocessing for this problem set.

I'm running 2.7 and using recursive locks despite their performance penalties.

My question is this: will I run into scaling problems with the GIL? I have seen no performance problems with it so far. Measuring this is...problematic. Is there a number of threads or something similar that you hit and it just starts choking? Does GIL performance differ significantly from executing multi-threaded code on a single-core CPU?

Thanks!

Comment: No one in their right mind would say the GIL guarantees thread safety. It exists to protect interpreter internals, so you won't actually crash, and coincidentally makes some types of operations (implemented in C, doing all the state dependent work in a single byte code instruction) atomic. But it can't make `x += 1` run safely in two different threads, because the byte code for that involves loading `x`, adding one, and storing back to `x`, and the interpreter can swap out the GIL at any step in between. The GIL isn't for logical safety, it's for interpreter integrity; use locks for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The GIL is a complex topic and the exact behavior in your case is hard to explain without your code. So I can not tell you if you will run into troubles in future. I can just advise to bring you project to a recent version of Python 3 if posdible. There have been many improvents made to the GIL in Python 3.

The is nothing like a magic number of threads at which Python will break. The general rule is just: The more threads, the more problem. Most complicated is going from one to two.

The GIL is released in some situations, especially when C code is executed or I/O is done. This allows code to run in parallel. With the advanced featured of modern CPUs is wouldn't be wise to limit your code to just one CPU.